# Does Android Lollipop 5.0 have Major Minor specification for Bluetooth Low Energy technology?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I just want to know if there is any Major or Minor for Bluetooh Low-Energy for Android in Lollipop 5.0.

As per I know, in Apple's iBeacon, there are a few identifiers that we can use to identify a specific iBeacon. They are UUID, Major and Minor.

However, in Lollipop 5.0, all I can notice is that we can get the UUID from the device. But I do not seem to see anything that tells how to get Major Minor value from the Bluetooth beacon signal.

Does this mean that BLE specification needs not have Major, Minor value and only Apple's iBeacon actually provides it? Is major, minor specification optional for the Beacon Manufacturer?